Cant install React Native on Mac
Edit: My original task was to get React Native working on my computer. However I have run into several problems doing so. I've traced the root of the issue to my ruby version, which will not update.
when I run
gem install bundler  

I get the following
bundler requires Ruby version >= 3.0.0. The current ruby version is 2.7.1.83.

and so I tried
rvm install ruby-3.1.1

which gives me
Error running '__rvm_make -j8',
please read /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/log/1714491493_ruby-3.1.1/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.

so essentially my issue is I am blocked from getting the correct version of ruby.
The following is my original post:
I tried following these directions : https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
I am running Sonoma 14.4.1 and a Mac with a M1 chip, XCode version 15.2, ruby version 2.7.1
when I get to this step
bundle install to install Bundler
i get the following error:
    21: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
    20: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
    19: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    18: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    17: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/exe/bundle:37:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:130:in `with_friendly_errors'
    15: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/exe/bundle:49:in `block in <top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/cli.rb:24:in `start'
    13: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    12: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/cli.rb:30:in `dispatch'
    11: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    10: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
     9: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
     8: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/cli.rb:258:in `install'
     7: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/settings.rb:133:in `temporary'
     6: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/cli.rb:259:in `block in install'
     5: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/cli/install.rb:52:in `run'
     4: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     3: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
     2: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/bundler-2.2.19/lib/bundler/fetcher.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': dlopen(/Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/-darwin22/zlib.bundle, 0x0009): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib/libz.1.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: <878913C8-6316-3212-A8AD-F9DD9EA034F5> /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/-darwin22/zlib.bundle
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib/libz.1.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib/libz.1.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib/libz.1.dylib' (no such file) - /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/-darwin22/zlib.bundle 

also worth noting when i try
bundle exec pod install i get the following
Could not find gem 'cocoapods (>= 1.13, < 1.15)' in rubygems repository https://rubygems.org/ or installed locally.
The source does not contain any versions of 'cocoapods'
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I've tried reinstalling homebrew.
I also tried
gem update --system 

which gives
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.7.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/-darwin22/openssl.bundle, 0x0009): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: <F1F803B3-9EF7-3EDD-A626-FE9DC2ABDBA4> /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/-darwin22/openssl.bundle
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file) - /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/-darwin22/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/gem-wrappers-1.4.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/-darwin22/openssl.bundle, 0x0009): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: <F1F803B3-9EF7-3EDD-A626-FE9DC2ABDBA4> /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/-darwin22/openssl.bundle
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file) - /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/-darwin22/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
ERROR:  Loading command: update (LoadError)
    dlopen(/Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/-darwin22/openssl.bundle, 0x0009): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: <F1F803B3-9EF7-3EDD-A626-FE9DC2ABDBA4> /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/-darwin22/openssl.bundle
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib' (no such file) - /Users/bekkiantonelli/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/-darwin22/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

i have tried using the terminal on rosetta and not on rosetta
any help would be appreciated!

try to use rvm for ruby installation, then gem install bundler for installing bundler, then bundle install, cd ios, pod install

okay, I thought I had ruby successfully installed. After trying this, I think my issue might be my ruby version will not update, which is why all the other fixes i've tried havent worked. Will work on that and update

https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5367 Might help

@engineersmnky that worked to download ruby, thank you!

Credits to @engineersmnky for linking the ruby update fix, I specifically used the line
rvm install ruby-3.3.0 --reconfigure --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@3)

this allowed me to actually update Ruby, which was the real issue. Then I was able to cd into the project and into ios and ran
bundle install
bundle exec pod install

and it ran correctly
